# iText - read check box value

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-reader, pdfstamper

I'm trying to read pdf form. I managed to get normal textbox value by doing this.
**Code**

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(RESULT1);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT2));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
String name = form.getField("Text1");//Check Box 1
System.out.println("Name "+name);
```

How do I get check box value. Please advice.

Comment: There should be no difference between getting the value of a normal text box and the value of a check box. Both values are to be retrieved with the `getField()` method. Have you tried? Are you sure you're using the correct name of the check box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bruno said in his comment, you should be able to get the value of a check box with the code you posted.  You can use `form.getAppearanceStates(NAME_OF_CHECKBOX)` to get a String array of possible values.  For a check box, these should be `Off` and `Yes`.

Comment: Yeah...there was issue in the field name. My field name has spaces.. Eg: "Check Box 1". Once i moved the space it works fine. To add on on your answer. Check box returns `Yes` and null.